# Android Studio justificationMode only shows in preview

Tags: android, mobile

Using Android Studio 4.1.1 and used the code **android:justificationMode="interword"** to justify textviews but I use bluestacks as an emulator and the justification only shows in previews and not when I run it through the emulator.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: android:justificationMode is available on api level >=26 make sure blue stack emulator installed with >=26

Comment: i have the latest blue stacks downloaded, how can i know if it is >=26 api?

Comment: Not sure about that actually but there might be some info inside bluestack ? I am not sure whether it works or not but give it a try ... go to settings inside bluestack emulated device os and from there you can see the android version just like normal device..

Comment: i identified that my sdk is 25, how can i make the api level of my blue stacks >= 26?

Comment: Again I am not sure about that ... search for it ....

Comment: okay thank you! i appreciate it!